# Case Statement in JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I have this query:

```
Select b.building_pk, bil.building_fk, bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk, b.ACTL_TNT_CT 
From [DB].[Schema].Building b (nolock)
left Join [DB].[Schema].Billing bil (nolock) on bil.building_fk = b.building_pk
join ##GlobalTempTable1 tt (nolock) on tt.Building_fk = b.building_pk
Order by b.building_pk;
```

It works fine. But I want to override `NULL`s in the result set in columns `bil.building_fk` and `bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk` as not everything in Billing tbl exists in building table.

So wrote the following query below, but getting this error message.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near '='.

Please assist.

```
SELECT b.building_pk, bil.building_fk As [BLD Key from Billing], bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk, b.ACTL_TNT_CT As [ActualTenantCount] 
FROM [DB].[Schema].Building b (nolock)
join ##GlobalTempTable1 tt (nolock) ON tt.Building_fk = b.building_pk
left Join [DB].[Schema].Billing bil (nolock) ON
CASE
    WHEN bil.building_fk IS NOT NULL 
        THEN bil.building_fk = b.building_pk AND bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk = bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk
    WHEN bil.building_fk IS NULL
        THEN bil.building_fk = NULL AND bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk = 'Not in Billing'
    END
ORDER BY b.building_pk;
```

Comment: You have multiple errors in your logic, such as `= NULL`.

Comment: CASE is not a statement, it's a function/expression.  It is supposed to return a value, not try to assign values.

Comment: You can't use a case expression like that. You have so many problems in here is it hard to address them all. Global temp tables. These are very problematic due to concurrency issues. You have NOLOCK littering everything. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ You have conditionals checking where a column = NULL. This will not work because nothing = NULL. those need to use ISNULL or COALESCE,

Comment: Also, many are not aware of it, but boolean/(conditional truth value) is not valid datatype in SQL and cannot be returned from an expression/function.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do because it's very wrong. I think, though, that you want to keep your `FROM` the same and do the `CASE` statement up into the SELECT.

```
Select b.building_pk, CASE WHEN bil.Building_fk IS NULL THEN 'Not in Billing' ELSE bil.building_fk END as building_fk, bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk, b.ACTL_TNT_CT 
From [DB].[Schema].Building b (nolock)
left Join [DB].[Schema].Billing bil (nolock) on bil.building_fk = b.building_pk
join ##GlobalTempTable1 tt (nolock) on tt.Building_fk = b.building_pk
Order by b.building_pk;
```

Or, better yet, use `COALESCE()` here:

```
Select b.building_pk, COALESCE(bil.Building_fk,'Not in Billing') as building_fk, bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk, b.ACTL_TNT_CT 
From [DB].[Schema].Building b (nolock)
left Join [DB].[Schema].Billing bil (nolock) on bil.building_fk = b.building_pk
join ##GlobalTempTable1 tt (nolock) on tt.Building_fk = b.building_pk
Order by b.building_pk;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the goal is to replace NULLs in column bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk when bil.Building_fk is NULL.

Comment: Then move that case statement over to that field and flip that Else to point to that other field.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` expressions can't be used to set which criteria you use for a `JOIN`, they can be used on either side of the comparison operator in `JOIN` criteria, but I don't think you need that, I think you just need a `LEFT JOIN` and a `COALESCE()` in your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT b.building_pk
     , bil.building_fk As [BLD Key from Billing]
     , COALESCE(bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk,'Not in Billing')
     , b.ACTL_TNT_CT As [ActualTenantCount] 
FROM [DB].[Schema].Building b 
join ##GlobalTempTable1 tt 
   ON tt.Building_fk = b.building_pk
left Join [DB].[Schema].Billing bil 
   ON bil.building_fk = b.building_pk
ORDER BY b.building_pk;
```

Edit: Noticed `BillingAccountStatus_fk` was coming from `bil` on both sides, so removed that from the `JOIN` criteria.

Comment: The goal is to replace NULLs in column bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk when bil.Building_fk is NULL

Comment: That's what this query is doing: `COALESCE()` returns the first non-null value from a set, in this case, if `bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk` is null it returns 'Not in Billing'

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT b.building_pk, bil.building_fk As [BLD Key from Billing], bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk, b.ACTL_TNT_CT As [ActualTenantCount] 
FROM [DB].[Schema].Building b (nolock)
join ##GlobalTempTable1 tt (nolock) ON tt.Building_fk = b.building_pk
left Join [DB].[Schema].Billing bil (nolock) ON
    (bil.building_fk IS NOT NULL AND 
        (bil.building_fk = b.building_pk AND bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk = bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk))
    OR (bil.building_fk IS NULL AND
        (bil.building_fk = NULL AND bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk = 'Not in Billing'))
ORDER BY b.building_pk;
```

I'll leave the misguided use of `nolock` for another day ...

Comment: I'm aware of the problems related to nolock usage, but I'm working in prod , so I was asked to never run anything without putting nolock....

Comment: I tried your query and it was successfully executed, but NULLs in bil.BillingAccountStatus_fk column were not replaced... Do I need to replace "=" in the "bil.building_fk = NULL" to "bil.building_fk IS NULL"? Just tried it with "IS NULL" did not help in NULLs replacement.